# How to properly set up a React project base?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app, prettier

I am trying to include:

- Typescript
- Eslint (Airbnb config)
- Prettier
- React 18 rc
- pre-commit hook to lint and format

I have tried to download them one by one according to each of their official documentations, but they don't play nice together, there will always be conflicting issues. I will set up the base project with create-react-app typescript template, install eslint for typescript, and the project would already immediately break as the linter points out all of the wrong things with the base project, some of them seemingly unfixable without changing the rules.

For example, one of the first problems I face is that the default CRA project does not include import names, violating import/extensions rule, but it doesn't recognize ts or tsx extensions when I do try to add them.

Is there a guide for setting up all of these dependencies properly? (React 18 rc is optional, but from what I see it doesn't break anything anyways)

Comment: From what I see, the problem is mostly with Eslint. Maybe you want to try another config for it, or exclude create-react-app files from it.

Comment: any particular config you would recommend? I have been using airbnb because it is the most popular one, and it didn't have any problem with my non-typescript react projects in the past

Comment: Not really... I mostly use Next.js instead of CRA, & it supports Eslint out-of-the-box.